# Add class to li on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow on from a previous question. What i want to achieve is to add a class to an li element after clicking an anchor tag which will render a new page. So i understand that when the page reloads new HTML is loaded and my addclass method will be forgotten.

So i have been looking into this and it seems as if there is still a way to do this with jquery? was hoping someone could perhaps clarify or let me know what is wrong with the following

So this is what i have.....

Navbar

```
 <ul id="main-menu" class="clearfix sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
        <li>
            <a href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/pages/aboutme"><i class="icon-desktop"></i> About Me</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/pages/portfolio"><i class="icon-picture"></i>  Portfolio</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/blog"><i class="icon-comments"></i> Blog</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/contact"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('#main-menu li').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  if (href === window.location.pathname) {
    $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
  }
});
```

Though this isnt working. Could anyone please explain why? or see an error in the code, my initial thoughts that are i need to find the a closest to the current li ?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Could you please replace your 'Navbar' source code with the actual rendered HTML? Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see if addClass gets executed?

Comment: apologies, added rendered HTML

Comment: Don't use "===", but "==".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put 1 line after href variable.

```
console.log(href)
```

You will understand easily what is going wrong there.
You need to see this in console. if you are not aware with this then use following.

```
alert(href)
```

Comment: I think this should be a comment

Comment: ah ok so console.log(href) gives /, which is undefined

Comment: So use absolute path in href. so that you get full path.

Comment: so window.location.href ?

Comment: in <a> tag href attribute. Write absolute path there.

Comment: Also try console.log(window.location.pathname). I think you are not getting right pathname. There is some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you take href from an a tag, maybe you should take href also from page? `if (href === window.location.href)` Anyway I am pretty sure the problem is in the if condition.